# Flask oauth: Unable to logout with gitlab as oauth provider

Tags: python, flask, cookies, oauth, flask-login

I'm using gitlab as oauth provider in a flask. I'm using flask_oauthlib and flask_login. My logout function works but then i am automatically logged in agin. Even with a private navigator.

Here is my code:

```
    class User(UserMixin):
        def __init__(self, user_id, access_token):
            self.id = user_id
            self.access_token = access_token

    #[...]
    @app.route('/')
    @login_required
    def index():
        return render_template("index.html", navitems=navitems)

    @app.route('/login')
    def login():
        callback_url = url_for('authorized', _external=True)
        return gitlab.authorize(callback=callback_url)

    @app.route('/logout')
    @login_required
    def logout():
        logout_user()
        session.pop('gitlab_token', None)
        response = make_response(redirect(url_for('index')))
        response.delete_cookie('sessionID')
        return response

    @app.route('/login/authorized')
    def authorized():
        response = gitlab.authorized_response()
        if response is None or response.get('access_token') is None:
            LOG.error('OAuth authorization failed: %s', response)
            return 'Access denied: reason={} error={}'.format(
                request.args['error_reason'],
                request.args['error_description']
            )
        session['gitlab_token'] = (response['access_token'], '')
        user_info = gitlab.get('user')
        user = User(user_info.data['username'], response['access_token'])
        login_user(user)
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Is someone experiments the same thing? I can share the rest of my code if needed. Thanks!

Comment: Update: I tried to add in my logout function a session.clear() and a revoke token function like this:

`def revoke_gitlab_token(access_token):
    gitlab_revoke_url = 'https://gitlab.com/oauth/revoke'
    client_id = os.environ.get("GITLAB_APP_KEY")  
    client_secret = os.environ.get("GITLAB_APP_SECRET") 
    payload = {
        'token': access_token,
        'client_id': client_id,
        'client_secret': client_secret
    }
    response = requests.post(gitlab_revoke_url, data=payload)`

But still I am automatically log in again.